# Write a function to improve readability and shorten script when using worldfootballR (RStudio)

Tags: r, function

I am working in RStudio and using worldfootballR package to scrape football (soccer) statistics (player market values) from the website transfermrkt.com.

I have written code that pulls player market values for a specific country and year (e.g., English Premier League 2020). I have also managed to group by team and sum the player market values to create a total team market value. Finally, I also have code that singles out those playing in defensive positions and sums the player market value for these players only - see the code below.

```
library(worldfootballR)
library(dplyr)
eng2020 <- tm_player_market_values(country_name = "England", start_year = 2020)
prem2020 <- eng2020 %>% 
  group_by(squad) %>% 
  summarise(tot_val = sum(player_market_value_euro, na.rm = TRUE))
prem2020def <- eng2020 %>%
  group_by(squad) %>%
  summarise(tot_cb = sum(player_market_value_euro[player_position=="Centre-Back"],
                         na.rm = TRUE),
            tot_lb = sum(player_market_value_euro[player_position=="Left-Back"],
                         na.rm = TRUE),
            tot_rb = sum(player_market_value_euro[player_position=="Right-Back"],
                         na.rm = TRUE))
Total <- c(prem2020def$tot_cb + prem2020def$tot_lb + prem2020def$tot_rb)
prem2020def <- cbind(prem2020def, Total)
```

However, I need to do this for many countries (15+) and across many years (6/7 years worth of data) and don't want a ridiculously long script. Could someone help me write a function that I can apply here to lighten the script I write and improve the readability for others?

Thanks, JB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following seems to work.
The function does what your posted code does but is more general, since it accepts a country and an year as arguments. The, call it in a `Map` loop on countries and years to get the data from.

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(worldfootballR)
  library(dplyr)
  library(tidyr)
})

computeTotals <- function(country, year, verbose = FALSE) {
  if(verbose) {
    msg <- sprintf("Processing %s, %d", country, year)
    message(msg)
  }
  data <- suppressWarnings(
    tm_player_market_values(country_name = country, start_year = year)
  )
  out <- data %>%
    filter(grepl("-Back", player_position)) %>%
    group_by(squad, player_position) %>%
    summarise(total = sum(player_market_value_euro, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = "drop") %>%
    drop_na() %>%
    mutate(player_position = sub("(^.)[^-]+-(.).*$", "\\1\\2", player_position),
           player_position = tolower(player_position)) %>%
    arrange(player_position) %>%
    pivot_wider(
      id_cols = squad,
      names_from = player_position,
      names_glue = "tot_{player_position}",
      values_from = total
    ) %>%
    arrange(squad) %>%
    mutate(tot_def = rowSums(.[2:4], na.rm = TRUE),
           country = country,
           year = year) %>%
    relocate(year, country) %>%
    left_join(
      data %>% 
        group_by(squad) %>% 
        summarise(tot_val = sum(player_market_value_euro, na.rm = TRUE)),
      by = join_by(squad)
    )
  out
}


Countries <- c("England", "Germany")
Years <- 2020:2022
input <- expand.grid(Years, Countries)[2:1]
names(input) <- c("Country", "Year")
input
#   Country Year
# 1 England 2020
# 2 England 2021
# 3 England 2022
# 4 Germany 2020
# 5 Germany 2021
# 6 Germany 2022

totals_list <- Map(computeTotals, input$Country, input$Year)
totals_list[[1]]

do.call(rbind, totals_list)
```

---

## Edit

After the OP's comment I have corrected the function to include total team value, not just defenders.
I have also added a new argument, `verbose` with default `FALSE`. Use as follows.

```
Map(computeTotals, input$Country, input$Year, verbose = TRUE)
```

Comment: thanks so much for this and thanks for your time. It does indeed work but I have noticed a couple of things: 1) as in the original code, I also want total player market value for the whole team (i.e., not just defenders), and 2) it seems to produce a lot of NAs which leaves teams with incorrect values (e.g., Man United 2020 should have cb = 98500000, lb = 65000000, and rb = 54000000 but in this cb = NA). Can we work something like `na.rm = TRUE` in to the function to get this to work? Thanks again

Comment: @jbrimm2004 Done 1) and 2), see now.

Comment: that has done it - thank you so much again! You are a legend